# HTML Anochor tag breaks into new line

Tags: html

When I add HTML Anchor tag on any word in my web page, it breaks into new line.

The paragraph

`A Web Page is a Hypertext Document`

becomes like this

```
A Web Page is a
Hypertext
Document
```

When link is set to `Hypertext` with the following code

```
<a href="#heading1">What is Web Page?</a>
```

This is my HTML Code

```
<p>A Web Page is a <a href="#hypertext">Hypertext</a> Document written in    any Markup Language . HTML is a&nbsp; Markup Language&nbsp; which is mostly used in Web Page designing.</p>
```

This is my CSS Code

body{background-color:rgba(196,213,220,0.05)}#body{min-height:90vh}a{text-decoration:none!important;outline:none!important;display:block}.flex-center{align-items:center;display:flex;justify-content:center}a.link{color:#636b6f;padding:0 25px;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:.1rem;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif}.padding-top-bottom-thirty{padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:15px}.mainhead{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(224,98,47,0.39);

What is the Problem?

Comment: Yes there was a display:block in my css

Answer (score 0):

`display:block` in your CSS is causing your problem. Just remove it:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none!important;
  outline: none!important;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(196, 213, 220, 0.05)
}
#body {
  min-height: 90vh
}
a {
  text-decoration: none!important;
  outline: none!important;
}
.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
a.link {
  color: #636b6f;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif
}
.padding-top-bottom-thirty {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px
}
.mainhead {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(224, 98, 47, 0.39);
```

```html
<p>A Web Page is a <a href="#hypertext">Hypertext</a> Document written in any Markup Language . HTML is a&nbsp; Markup Language&nbsp; which is mostly used in Web Page designing.</p>
```